# Aggregate Pandas Columns on Geospacial Distance

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial

I have a dataframe that has 3 columns, Latitude, Longitude and Median_Income.  I need to get the average median income for all points within x km of the original point into a 4th column. I need to do this for each observation.

I have tried making 3 functions which I use apply to attempt to do this quickly.  However, the dataframes take forever to process (hours).  I haven't seen an error yet, so it appears to be working okay.

The Haversine formula, I found on here.  I am using it to calculate the distance between 2 points using lat/lon.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    #Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    #on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

My hav_checker function will check the distance of the current row against all other rows returning a dataframe with the haversine distance in a column.

```
def hav_checker(row, lon, lat):

    hav = haversine(row['longitude'], row['latitude'], lon, lat)

    return hav
```

My value grabber fucntion uses the frame returned by hav_checker to return the mean value from my target column (median_income).

For reference, I am using the California housing dataset to build this out.

```
def value_grabber(row, frame, threshold, target_col):

    frame = frame.copy()

    frame['hav'] = frame.apply(hav_checker, lon = row['longitude'], lat = row['latitude'], axis=1)

    mean_tar = frame.loc[frame.loc[:,'hav'] <= threshold, target_col].mean()

    return mean_tar
```

I am trying to return these 3 columns to my original dataframe for a feature engineering project within a larger class project.

```
df['MedianIncomeWithin3KM'] = df.apply(value_grabber, frame=df, threshold=3, target_col='median_income', axis=1)

df['MedianIncomeWithin1KM'] = df.apply(value_grabber, frame=df, threshold=1, target_col='median_income', axis=1)

df['MedianIncomeWithinHalfKM'] = df.apply(value_grabber, frame=df, threshold=.5, target_col='median_income', axis=1)
```

I have been able to successfully do this with looping but it is extremely time intensive and need a faster solution.

Comment: Can you include some example data, so we can actually run the code?

Answer (score 4):

## vectorization

You are doing all the calculations in normal python space. Try to do as much as possible in numpy space

### dummy data

```
np.random.seed(0)
coords = (np.random.random(size=(N, dim)) - 0.5) * 360
median_income = np.random.normal(size=N) * 10000 + 5000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "lat": coords[:, 0],
        "lon": coords[:, 1],
        "median_income": np.random.normal(size=N) * 10000 + 30000,
    }
)
```

instead of using `math.radians`, use`np.radians` to calculate this for the whole matrix at once:

```
coords_rad = np.radians(df[["lat", "lon"]].values)
```

### select only the upper triangle

For this section, I borrowed a bit from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570681/1562285)

```
p1, p2 = np.triu_indices(N,k=1)        # k=1 eliminates diagonal indices
```

### havesine distances

```
lat1, lon1 = coords_rad[p1].T
lat2, lon2 = coords_rad[p2].T
d_lat = lat2 - lat1
d_lon = lon2 - lon1
r = 6371
distances = 2 * r * np.arcsin(
    np.sqrt(
        np.sin(d_lat / 2) ** 2
        + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(d_lon / 2) ** 2
    )
)
```

> ```
> array([ 6318.56953693,  5685.87555152,  8221.15833653,  6489.20595509,
>         8755.09024969,  7805.61189508,  6919.53162119, 15295.76892719,
>         8706.83662262,  8113.95651365, 14532.71048537, 11780.39186778,
>         7556.99686671, 11832.44825307,  7137.04783302,  9306.23652045,
>         5446.80037496,  8740.28196777, 10242.77405649, 14237.95015622,
>        12225.48901658,  2112.82250374, 11830.45390613, 13194.16431067,
>         3966.47195107, 11375.98162917,  5385.20026834, 10745.8851006 ,
>        15975.57051313, 13621.58550369,  7573.94148257,  2037.20795034,
>        12284.11555433, 17912.47114836,  9676.18614574,  6000.06279665,
>        14392.65091451, 11339.26110213,  2465.57715011, 14204.32921867,
>        15974.00480201,  8347.16187191,  9820.5895048 , 12576.27804606,
>         9720.35934264])
> ```

A way to minimize the memory footprint of this is by choosing the correct `dtype` by adding `.astype("e")` for example. The correct `dtype` for this application is the smallest one that still delivers the necessary resolution, so needs to be chosen with your data taken into consideration.

### Distance matrix

You can assemble a distance matrix

```
distance_matrix = np.zeros((N, N))
distance_matrix [(p1, p2)] = distances 
distance_matrix [(p2, p1)] = distances
```

> ```
>  array([[    0.        ,  6318.56953693,  5685.87555152,  8221.15833653,  6489.20595509,  8755.09024969,  7805.61189508,  6919.53162119, 15295.76892719,  8706.83662262],
>        [ 6318.56953693,     0.        ,  8113.95651365, 14532.71048537, 11780.39186778,  7556.99686671, 11832.44825307,  7137.04783302,  9306.23652045,  5446.80037496],
>        [ 5685.87555152,  8113.95651365,     0.        ,  8740.28196777, 10242.77405649, 14237.95015622, 12225.48901658,  2112.82250374, 11830.45390613, 13194.16431067],
>        [ 8221.15833653, 14532.71048537,  8740.28196777,     0.        ,  3966.47195107, 11375.98162917,  5385.20026834, 10745.8851006 , 15975.57051313, 13621.58550369],
>        [ 6489.20595509, 11780.39186778, 10242.77405649,  3966.47195107,     0.        ,  7573.94148257,  2037.20795034, 12284.11555433, 17912.47114836,  9676.18614574],
>        [ 8755.09024969,  7556.99686671, 14237.95015622, 11375.98162917,  7573.94148257,     0.        ,  6000.06279665, 14392.65091451, 11339.26110213,  2465.57715011],
>        [ 7805.61189508, 11832.44825307, 12225.48901658,  5385.20026834,  2037.20795034,  6000.06279665,     0.        , 14204.32921867, 15974.00480201,  8347.16187191],
>        [ 6919.53162119,  7137.04783302,  2112.82250374, 10745.8851006 , 12284.11555433, 14392.65091451, 14204.32921867,     0.        ,  9820.5895048 , 12576.27804606],
>        [15295.76892719,  9306.23652045, 11830.45390613, 15975.57051313, 17912.47114836, 11339.26110213, 15974.00480201,  9820.5895048 ,     0.        ,  9720.35934264],
>        [ 8706.83662262,  5446.80037496, 13194.16431067, 13621.58550369,  9676.18614574,  2465.57715011,  8347.16187191, 12576.27804606,  9720.35934264,     0.        ]])
> ```

Then you can use

```
close_points = pd.DataFrame(np.where((distance_matrix < d_crit) & (0 < distance_matrix)), index=["p1", "p2"]).T
```

To get the points which are closer than the critical distance (4km in your case, 10000km for this dummy data).

Another way to get the close points without assembling the `distance_matrix` is this:

```
point_combinations = np.array((p1, p2)).T
close_points = pd.DataFrame(
    np.concatenate(  # if A is close to B, B is close to A
        (
            point_combinations[np.ix_(close, [0, 1])],
            point_combinations[np.ix_(close, [1, 0])],   # if A is close to B, B is close to A
        )
    ),
    columns=["p1", "p2"],
)
```

Then get the mean of the close median incomes, you could use `DataFrame.groupby`

```
df["neighbours_mean"] = close_points.groupby("p1").apply(
    lambda x: (df.loc[x["p2"], "median_income"]).mean()
)
```

> ```
>   lat lon median_income   neighbours_mean
> 0 17.57286141383691   77.468171894071 30457.58517301446   30794.78854097742
> 1 36.994815385791796  16.15794587888287   28128.161499741665  29640.567671359968
> 2 -27.484272237994304 52.5218807039962    45327.79214358458   28367.842422379927
> 3 -22.468603945430697 141.0382802815487   44693.58769900285   32114.24852431677
> 4 166.91859378037054  -41.961053222720025 31549.474256969163  32323.686056555547
> 5 105.02101370975925  10.402171111045613  33781.625196021734  28564.170628892793
> 6 24.49604199381563   153.21478978535797  21122.142523698873  34409.152403209606
> 7 -154.4270190487607  -148.63345210744535 10192.035317760732  32608.604330769795
> 8 -172.72137692148274 119.74314439725768  26520.878506738474  23294.56216951406
> 9 100.13643034194618  133.2043733688549   31563.489691039802  28593.31119269739
> ```

please test this against a sample set of your data

---

## memory

If you still run into memory problems, you'll need to start calculation the distances in chunks, and then later concatenate them. An alternative is to use [`dask`](https://dask.org/) instead of `pandas` and `numpy`

Comment: I was able to get this solution to work.  It's many times faster, however I did run into some memory issues along the way.